# Linux Throws Error: Can't read CTR while intializing i8042?

Tags: boot, encryption

My install of linux throws the following errors upon boot:

```
efi: requested map not found.
esrt: ESRT header is not in the memory map.
i0842: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042.
```

Would these errors be indicative factors of disk corruption?

Comment: efi relates to (U)EFI vs. legacy BIOS boot. ESRT is probably some ACPI area. i8042 is the PS/2 keyboard/mouse controller. None of this points to disk corruption, unless your kernel image is corrupted. But it looks more like it's a UEFI boot problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your modern motherboard has no i8042 controller chip, but the most of board has (green, purple, round) PS/2 keyboard, mouse port for legacy BIOS compatibility.
Usually, the (U)EFI/BIOS controls keyboard and mouse via USB as HID device default.

But, very old hardware and OS detect i8042 controller and search keyboard and mouse on boot, and display the error above.
The error is no relation with hard disks, and can be ignored unless you cannot use the keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message. In my case, the keyboard and the trackstick/touchpad didn't work. (Thinkpad W541, Opensuse 15.0, Kernel 4.12.14).

I fixed it by removing the kernel opts `acpi=off` and `apm=off` in the grub-setup.

Answer (score 0):

This error occured to me after the exchange of the faulty motherboard of my Lenovo T14 laptop. I've fixed it by disabling secure boot in UEFI.